# Python: visualize solution of differential equation

Tags: python, differential-equations, vpython

I try to simulate the motion of a gyroscope using python. For this I solve a differential equation numerically (which works fine), but now I want objects to move according to the solution of the differential equation. I have seen many examples where the solution is plotted (or even animated in a plot), so I was wondering if it is possible to use the solution for the manipulation of graphical objects, too.

I hope I made it clear what I intend to do. I really appreciate your help!!!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you can use [turtle graphics](https://docs.python.org/2/library/turtle.html) if you have it move to arbitrarily placed dots along the equation line.